# Dynamically generate code having filter, withColumnRenamed and coalesce condition Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dynamic

I have a piece of code which I want to generate dynamically. I want to take below columns in the form of a list or Sequence and perform `filter` operation with `coalesce` inside, `drop` and `withColumnRenamed` statements.

Here the list of columns that I want to accept dynamically (here as a string).

```
val cols = "a|tmp_a,b|tmp_b"
```

The code looks something like this:

```
val df1 = df2.filter(!(coalesce(col("a"), lit(0)) === coalesce(col("tmp_a"), lit(0))) || !(upper(col("b")) === upper(col("tmp_b"))))
  .drop("a")
  .drop("b")
  .withColumnRenamed("tmp_a", "a")
  .withColumnRenamed("tmp_b", "b")
```

If more columns are added to `cols`, how can the code be adapted dynamically? New column pairs should use the same filter condition as the "b|tmp_b" above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an input with the pairs of column names, you can create the two types of filter conditions (below the first column pair uses the first filter pattern and the rest uses the second). After the dataframe is filtered, the `drop` and `withColumnRenamed` can be applied using a `foldLeft`.

```
val cols = "a|tmp_a,b|tmp_b,c|tmp_c".split(",").map(_.split("\\|"))

val filterCondHead = !(coalesce(col(cols.head(0)), lit(0)) === coalesce(col(cols.head(1)), lit(0)))
val filterCondTail = cols.tail.map(c => !(upper(col(c(0))) === upper(col(c(1))))).reduce(_ || _)

val df2 = df.filter(filterCondHead || filterCondTail)

val df3 = cols.foldLeft(df2){ case(df, c) => 
  df.drop(c(0)).withColumnRenamed(c(1), c(0))
}
```

Comment: I Request you to please help me with the below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784889/generate-id-in-spark-as-per-the-below-logic-in-spark